# Accessing object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On last.fm I need to link to the list of the most popular tracks. The error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'track' of undefined" appears. How can I access the "name" property?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
    
    export default class App extends Component {
        state={
            data: [],
        }
        async componentDidMount() {
            const response = await
                fetch(`http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=tag.gettoptracks&tag=disco&api_key=f21dfa58ed2c6c4a65227b8f730c281b&format=json`,
                )
            const data = await response.json();
            this.setState({
                data: data,
            })
        }
        render() {
            const{data} = this.state
    
           console.log (data.tracks.track.name)//TypeError: Cannot read property 'track' of undefined
    
            return (
                <div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: `track` is also an array, you you can't access `track.name`

Answer (score 1):

On the first render (at least), your state will only be the state you set in your constructor, so naturally `data.tracks` is undefined. (Note also that your initial state has `data` as an array, but you're using it as a non-array object when you do `data.tracks`. I assume what you receive must be an object rather than an array. But I suspect `data.tracks` is an array, so you'd probably want `data.tracks[x].name` where `x` is an index, and you probably want to initialize state to `{data: {tracks: []}}` or `{data: null}` to indicate you're loading the data.)

You have two options. Either:

1. Allow for the fact you may not have the data yet when rendering, or
2. Don't fetch the data in this component; instead, fetch it in the parent component and don't render this component until you have the data (which you'd pass as a prop).

Answer (score 1):

The `data` is an empty array initially. Only try to access the nested data once the response has come back and the array has been populated. Using hooks, you could do something like the following:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [tracks, setTracks] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=tag.gettoptracks&tag=disco&api_key=f21dfa58ed2c6c4a65227b8f730c281b&format=json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setTracks(result.tracks);
      });
      //.catch(handleErrors);
  }, []);
  if (tracks) {
    console.log(tracks.track[0].name);
  }
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  )
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```